# How to allow site members with read permission the ability to participate in discussion board on same site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, custom-permission-level

I am using `Sharepoint Server 2013` and I have a list of users who have read only access at the top-level site. I have created a Discussion board on a sub-site (that branches out directly from that top-level site). This sub-site also contains a library with several Excel reports.

The users from the sub-site have inherited the same permissions from the parent site (ie: the top-level site) and hence, they have only a read access in the discussion board.

How do I go about changing their permissions for the discussion board? Do I need to break the inheritance to the parent site?

I am new to Sharepoint and we do not have a Sharepoint administrator in place. So, I want to be very cautious before moving forward with this.

Answer (score 0):

For OOB function, you could break permission for discussion board list and grant proper permission for users so they could have permission to it.